# How to mock SignalR used in a service layer

Tags: .net, .net-core, mocking, signalr, xunit

I need to test `ClientConnectionProvider` class, but can not mock `private IHubContext<SignalrServerHub, IBroadcast> HubContext { get; set; }` in test class given below. How can I mock client in `hubcontext` used in test class?

```
public class ClientConnectionProvider : IConnectionProvider
{
    private readonly ILogger<ClientConnectionProvider> logger;
    
    private IHubContext<SignalrServerHub, IBroadcast> HubContext { get; set;}
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ClientConnectionProvider"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    /// <param name="hubContext"></param>
    public ClientConnectionProvider(ILogger<ClientConnectionProvider> logger, IHubContext<SignalrServerHub, IBroadcast> hubContext)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        HubContext = hubContext;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// To create and save  a connection based on clients on connect.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="groupName"><see cref="string"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>Task of <see cref="Task"/>.</returns>
    public async Task<ServiceMethodResponse> SubscribeConnectionToAGroup(ClientConnection connection)
    {
        await HubContext.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connection.ConnectionId, "HubUsers");
    
        return new ServiceMethodResponse() 
        {
            IsSuccess = true,
            IsValid = true,
            Message = "Subscribed to a group"
        };
    }
}

public class ConnectionProviderTest
{
    private Mock<ILogger<ClientConnectionProvider>> logger;
    private Mock<IDispatcher> dispatcher;
    private Mock<IServiceProvider> serviceProvider;
    private Mock<IConnectionProvider> connectionProvider;
    private Mock<IHubContext<SignalrServerHub, IBroadcast>> HubContext;
    //Mock<IClientProxy> mockClientProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
    private Mock<IClientProxy> mockClientProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();    

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ConnectionProviderTest"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ConnectionProviderTest()
    {
        this.logger = new Mock<ILogger<ClientConnectionProvider>>();
        this.HubContext = new Mock<IHubContext<SignalrServerHub, IBroadcast>>();
        this.connectionProvider = new Mock<IConnectionProvider>();
        this.dispatcher = new Mock<IDispatcher>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task SendNotificationToAllFoundSuccess()
    {    
        Mock<IHubClients> mockClients = new Mock<IHubClients>();
        Mock<IClientProxy> mockClientProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
        mockClients.Setup(clients => clients.All).Returns(mockClientProxy.Object);
        ClientConnectionProvider clientConnectionProvider = new ClientConnectionProvider( this.logger.Object, this.HubContext.Object);

        this.HubContext.Setup(x => x.Clients).Returns(() => (IHubClients<IBroadcast>)mockClients.Object);

        NotificationPayload payload = new NotificationPayload
        {
            Message = "RnadomHashString",
            SubscriptionTypes = new List<SubscriptionType>() { new SubscriptionType { SubscriptionTypeName = "HubUsers" } },
        };

        ServiceMethodResponse response = await clientConnectionProvider.SendNotificationToAll(payload).ConfigureAwait(true);
        Assert.True(response.IsValid);
    }
}
```

How do I test ClientConnectionProvider's methods? Getting error System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type `` 'Castle.Proxies.IHubClients`1Proxy' `` to type `` 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubClients`1[Platform.PushNotification.Services.SignalRHub.IBroadcast]' ``.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not make myself clear before. What I meant to say:

- you could wrap the instance of SignalrServerHub used in IHubContext in your actual code.
- you could then mock that interface.

The exception you are getting is because the class SignalrServerHub cannot be mocked, as it is not interfaced.

```
// The wrapper interface
public interface ISignalrServerHub
{
    // Specify the methods / properties of SignalrServerHub, which you need
    void SomeMethodYouNeed();
    bool SomeMethodWithReturnValue();
}

// The wrapper
public class WrappedSignalrServerHub : ISignalrServerHub
{
    private SingalrServerHub _wrappedInstance;
    
    public WrappedSignalrServerHub(SignalrServerHub instance)
    {
        _wrappedInstance = instance; // TODO add null check
    }
    
    public void SomeMethodYouNeed()
    {
        _wrappedInstance.SomeMethodYouNeed();
    }
    
    public bool SomeMethodWithReturnValue()
    {
        return _wrappedInstance.SomeMethodWithReturnValue();
    }
}

// The changed class
public class ClientConnectionProvider : IConnectionProvider
{
    private readonly ILogger<ClientConnectionProvider> logger;
    
    private IHubContext<ISignalrServerHub, IBroadcast> HubContext { get; set;}
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ClientConnectionProvider"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    /// <param name="hubContext"></param>
    public ClientConnectionProvider(ILogger<ClientConnectionProvider> logger, IHubContext<ISignalrServerHub, IBroadcast> hubContext)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        HubContext = hubContext;
    }
    
    // [snipped for brevity]
}

// The changed test
public class ConnectionProviderTest
{
    // [snipped for brevity]
    private Mock<IHubContext<ISignalrServerHub, IBroadcast>> HubContext;
    // [snipped for brevity]

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ConnectionProviderTest"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ConnectionProviderTest()
    {
        this.logger = new Mock<ILogger<ClientConnectionProvider>>();
        this.HubContext = new Mock<IHubContext<ISignalrServerHub, IBroadcast>>();
        this.connectionProvider = new Mock<IConnectionProvider>();
        this.dispatcher = new Mock<IDispatcher>();
    }

    
    // [snipped for brevity]
}
```

Comment: This does not help.

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe this will serve your needs.